# Error while accessing custom schema file and impose the schema to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a schema defined in a cloud storage. While reading data in pyspark dataframe I would like to impose the same schema.

Schema file format is schema.txt (Placed in cloud bucket)

```
[StructField('_corrupt_record', StringType(), True),StructField('id', StructType([ StructField('_data', StringType(), True) ])), StructField('clusterTime', StructType([   StructField('_timestamp' , StructType([ StructField('i',IntegerType(), True)]))])),StructField('fullDocument', StructType([StructField('seg' , StructType([ StructField('ap_lan',StringType(), True),StructField('mcd',IntegerType(), True),StructField('dd',StringType(), True), StructField('fgr',StringType(), True),StructField('na',StringType(), True)]))])),StructField('nh', StringType(), True)]
```

Code is as below :

````
import json
import ast
from google.cloud import storage
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (StructField, StringType, StructType, IntegerType, FloatType,LongType,BooleanType)

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()
spark_session.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)

def get_configs():
    print("Inside get configs ")
    with open("config.json") as json_data_file:
        data = json.load(json_data_file)
    input_schema = get_schema(data)
    return input_schema
  
def get_schema(data):
    """This function loads the given schema of all the events from cloud bucket available"""
    client = storage.Client()
    project_name = data["env_args"]["project"]
    bucket_name = data["env_args"]["bucket_name"]
    file_name = data["env_args"]["file_name"]
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
    schema_blob = blob.download_as_string()
    return schema_blob

#The call goes to config file which informs which bucket and file is to be read.

schema = get_configs()   ```It returns datatype as bytes so I convert it to String using decode('utf-8') ```

change_struct = schema.decode('utf-8')
final_struct = StructType(fields=change_struct)

df = spark_session.read.option("multiline","true")\
                   .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
                   .option("primitivesAsString", "false")\
                   .schema(final_struct)\
                   .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")\
                   .option("allowFieldAddition","true")\
                   .json(x)

df.show(truncate=True)
````

Error message:

```
    final_struct = StructType(fields=final_struct1)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 492, in __init__
    self.names = [f.name for f in fields]
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 492, in <listcomp>
    self.names = [f.name for f in fields]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

**Things I tried :**

When the schema was defined in the code itself it was working fine.

```
import json
import ast
from google.cloud import storage
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (StructField, StringType, StructType, IntegerType, FloatType,LongType,BooleanType)

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()
spark_session.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)

final_struct = StructType([StructField('_corrupt_record', StringType(), True),StructField('id', StructType([ StructField('_data', StringType(), True) ])), StructField('clusterTime', StructType([   StructField('_timestamp' , StructType([ StructField('i',IntegerType(), True)]))])),StructField('fullDocument', StructType([StructField('seg' , StructType([ StructField('ap_lan',StringType(), True),StructField('mcd',IntegerType(), True),StructField('dd',StringType(), True), StructField('fgr',StringType(), True),StructField('na',StringType(), True)]))])),StructField('nh', StringType(), True)])

df = spark_session.read.option("multiline","true")\
                   .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
                   .option("primitivesAsString", "false")\
                   .schema(final_struct)\
                   .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")\
                   .option("allowFieldAddition","true")\
                   .json(x)
```

Please help me understand what is going wrong here .

**Updated schema file: Serialized the schema in json format as below:**

```
{"type": "struct", "fields": [{"name": "_corrupt_record", "type": "string", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "id", "type": {"type": "struct", "fields": [{"name": "_data", "type": "string", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}]}, "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "clusterTime", "type": {"type": "struct", "fields": [{"name": "_timestamp", "type": {"type": "struct", "fields": [{"name": "i", "type": "integer", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}]}, "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}]}, "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "fullDocument", "type": {"type": "struct", "fields": [{"name": "sg", "type": {"type": "struct", "fields": [{"name": "col1", "type": "string", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "col2", "type": "integer", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "col3", "type": "string", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "col4", "type": "string", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "col5", "type": "string", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}]}, "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}]}, "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}, {"name": "operationType", "type": "string", "nullable": true, "metadata": {}}]}
```

Now Tried below code to read the custom schema from a json file format.

```
import json
import ast
from google.cloud import storage
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (StructField, StringType, StructType, IntegerType, FloatType,LongType,BooleanType)

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()
spark_session.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)

with open("/home/path/schema.json") as f:
     new_schema = StructType.fromJson(json.load(f))
     final_schema = new_schema.simpleString()
     print(final_schema)
print('\n\n')
df = spark_session.read.option("multiline","true")\
                   .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
                   .option("primitivesAsString", "false")\
                   .schema(final_schema)\
                   .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")\
                   .option("allowFieldAddition","true")\
                   .json(x)
```

final_schema gets printed as :

```
struct<_corrupt_record:string,id:struct<_data:string>,clusterTime:struct<_timestamp:struct<i:int>>,fullDocument:struct<sg:struct<col1:string,col2:int,col3:string,col4:string,col5:string>>,operationType:string>
```

But further while passing the same in dataframe read , it gives error as

```
  File "/home/tes/test_driver.py", line 58, in dstream_to_rdd
    .schema(final_schema)\
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 103, in schema
    self._jreader = self._jreader.schema(schema)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
extraneous input '<' expecting {'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANTI', 'ANY', 'ARCHIVE', 'ARRAY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AT', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'BETWEEN', 'BOTH', 'BUCKET', 'BUCKETS', 'BY', 'CACHE', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CHANGE', 'CHECK', 'CLEAR', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTERED', 'CODEGEN', 'COLLATE', 'COLLECTION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMPACT', 'COMPACTIONS', 'COMPUTE', 'CONCATENATE', 'CONSTRAINT', 'COST', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_USER', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', DATABASES, 'DBPROPERTIES', 'DEFINED', 'DELETE', 'DELIMITED', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DIRECTORIES', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'DIV', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'END', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EXCEPT', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTERNAL', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILTER', 'FILEFORMAT', 'FIRST', 'FOLLOWING', 'FOR', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FORMATTED', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FUNCTION', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GROUP', 'GROUPING', 'HAVING', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INNER', 'INPATH', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'INSERT', 'INTERSECT', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'IS', 'ITEMS', 'JOIN', 'KEYS', 'LAST', 'LATERAL', 'LAZY', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCATION', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGICAL', 'MACRO', 'MAP', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'NAMESPACE', 'NAMESPACES', 'NATURAL', 'NO', NOT, 'NULL', 'NULLS', 'OF', 'ON', 'ONLY', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONS', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUT', 'OUTER', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', 'OVER', 'OVERLAPS', 'OVERLAY', 'OVERWRITE', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONED', 'PARTITIONS', 'PERCENT', 'PIVOT', 'PLACING', 'POSITION', 'PRECEDING', 'PRIMARY', 'PRINCIPALS', 'PROPERTIES', 'PURGE', 'QUERY', 'RANGE', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'RECOVER', 'REDUCE', 'REFERENCES', 'REFRESH', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'RESTRICT', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', RLIKE, 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROLLUP', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'SCHEMA', 'SELECT', 'SEMI', 'SEPARATED', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'SESSION_USER', 'SET', 'MINUS', 'SETS', 'SHOW', 'SKEWED', 'SOME', 'SORT', 'SORTED', 'START', 'STATISTICS', 'STORED', 'STRATIFY', 'STRUCT', 'SUBSTR', 'SUBSTRING', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'TBLPROPERTIES', TEMPORARY, 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TIME', 'TO', 'TOUCH', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTION', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'TRANSFORM', 'TRIM', 'TRUE', 'TRUNCATE', 'TYPE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'UNBOUNDED', 'UNCACHE', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSET', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'USER', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VIEW', 'VIEWS', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', 'WITH', 'ZONE', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 6)
```

Comment: You're conflating schema that is just text with python code objects. You would need a way to deserialize such text back as code objects even though they are similar. Why are you not serializing the schema in JSON format instead (`final_struct.jsonValue()`) and storing that in the bucket? You can get back the same struct `StructType.fromJson(change_struct)`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I did not really follow. Could you please elaborate on your suggestion for serializing the schema first and then put to bucket.  what will be the benefits?

Comment: The benefit is that you can deserialize the JSON representation of the schema  into Python representation of the schema without lifting a finger to write a custom parser.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I have added my custom schema json file having schema defined  as above under bold line tag  ```Updated schema file: Serialized the schema in json format``` and now when  I try to read the custom schema in a dataframe it give jsondeocdeerror.